# Finding location of mongo source on Alpine linux

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux, locate

I'm in an Alpine container and wish to find the location where `apk add mongodb` installed the mongo source code.

I tried installing some packages for locating files (`whatis`, `whereis`, `locate`...) but none came down with a simple `apk add $PACKAGE` so I'm not sure how best to search around.

Does anyone know how I can quickly find the path to the Mongo source in Alpine linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `apk` packages don't generally contain source code, but rather pre-compiled binaries. The contents of the `mongodb` package can be found [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=mongodb&arch=x86_64&repo=community).

The [log file](http://build.alpinelinux.org/buildlogs/build-edge-x86_64/community/mongodb/mongodb-3.6.3-r2.log) associated with the latest build of the package indicates that the source was pulled down from http://downloads.mongodb.org/src/mongodb-src-r3.6.3.tar.gz by the build machine, but I wouldn't expect those contents to be present on a machine that just `apk add`s the `mongodb` package.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianAlexander, this accords with what I'm seeing on the box. I was looking for `mongodump / mongorestore` for which I had to `apk add mongodb-tools`